# How to print WeScheme programs?

Tags: printing, racket, wescheme

If it is a small program that fits into the screen, the default Print option in the browser does a good job. However, the colour combinations are not necessarily ideal for a print-out.

When the length of the program does not fit the screen, the default Print command in the browser does not capture the full extent of the program. Is there any other way to print other than cut-and-paste the code into an editor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmmm... good question.  My apologies!  At the moment, I don't have a command that makes it easy to render the whole program as a single page for printing.  The best option available right now is copy-and-paste.  I'm adding this as [issue 54](https://github.com/dyoo/WeScheme/issues/54) on the bug tracker.

Comment: Could you add a tag "wescheme" - so that I can use it to tag my future questions? I don't have sufficient reputation to do it myself. Thanks,

Comment: No problem!  I've added the tag.